# How to disprove $8q^2+15=7m^2$ for any integral value of $q$ and $m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> **Question Statement:-**
>
> Show that the quadratic equation $x^2+7x-14(q^2+1)=0$, where $q$ is an integer, has no integral roots.

---

**My attempt at a solution:-**

For the given quadratic equation having rational coefficients  to have integral roots the discriminant $D$ of the equation needs to be a perfect square.

$$\therefore D=(7)^2+56(q^2+1)=56q^2+105=7(8q^2+15)$$

Now, from the expression for the discriminant we see that $(8q^2+15)$ is always odd so for the discriminant to be a perfect square, the following condition needs to be satisfied

$$8q^2+15=7(2n+1)^2,\qquad\qquad\text{where n $\in Z$}$$

So $$2(q^2+1)=7(n^2+n)$$

After this I was having trouble coming up with a way to disprove the above equality that I came up with, if you could help me out as to how to proceed from here on or maybe suggest a way that makes it easier for me to prove what the question asks.

Comment: Modulo $7$ you get $q^2+1 \equiv 0 \mod 7$, which has no solution.

Answer (score 5):

If $7(8q^2+15)$ is a perfect square, $8q^2+15$ is divisible by $7$, which is equivalent to $q^2 \equiv -1 \pmod 7$. This is well known to be impossible.

Comment: I don't know any rules about modulo, can you explain it in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a root of $x^2+7x-14(q^2+1)=0$, then $x$ is a multiple of $7$ because $x^2=7(-x+2(q^2+1))$.

Write $x=7y$. Then $7(y^2+y)=2(q^2+1)$ and so $7$ divides $q^2+1$. But this cannot happen because $7 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. Or you can just check all possible residues of $q \bmod 7$ and see that $q^2+1$ is never $0$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006031/prove-that-a2-1-cannot-have-prime-factor-of-the-form-4k-3.

Comment: why is it that the root of the equation $x^2+7x-14(q^2+1)=0$ should be a multiple of $7$?

Comment: @user350331, see my fixed answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$8q^2+15=7m^2\Rightarrow q^2+1\equiv 0\pmod 7$$ but $q^2=-1$ has no solution in $\Bbb F_7$ because $(\Bbb F_7)^2=\{1,2,4,0\}$.

Actually $8q^2+15$ never is a multiple of $7$.

Comment: I do see that all the solutions contain the use of modulo but yours uses something more, which blew my mind even further away ;P. Can you please explain just the modulo part in detail. I dont know much about modulo except that it calculates remainder.

Comment: Can you tell me, why is that, that $8q^2+15$ is never a multiple of 7?

Comment: With pleasure. $8q^2+15=7(q^2+2)+q^2+1$ therefore the remainder you mention  modulo $7$  is $q^2+1$ and $7m^2$ has remainder $0$. Besides the squares modulo $7$ of $1,2,3,4,5,6,0$ are respectively equal to $1,4,2,2,4,1,0$ so any square is equal to $6=-1$.

Comment: @user350331: because  my deduction does not pay attention to the square of $m$, it is just because RHS is a multiple of $7$.

Comment: As $q^2+1=7(m^2-q^2-2) \implies q^2+1\equiv 0\pmod 7$. So, what this basically means is that either $q^2=6$ or $-1$, but both are not possible. Am I right, just confirming what I got from your solution, because I was not able to understand halfway what you tried to tell me in your comment.

Comment: $6=-1$ is not an usual equality of integers but an equality in $\Bbb F_7$ i.e. an equality of classes modulo $7$, you have $6\equiv -1\pmod 7\iff 6+1=7\equiv 0\pmod 7$. Good by. No more comments.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2+7x-14(q^2+1)=0$, where $x,q\in\mathbb Z$, then $$7\mid 7\left(2\left(q^2+1\right)-x\right)=x^2$$ so by [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $7\mid x$, so $7^2\mid x^2$ and $7^2\mid 7x$, so $$7^2\mid x^2+7x=7\left(2\left(q^2+1\right)\right),$$

so $7\mid 2\left(q^2+1\right)$. Since $\gcd(7,2)=1$, by [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $7\mid q^2+1$, i.e. $q^2\equiv -1\pmod{7}$, which is impossible, because $0^2\equiv 0$, $(\pm 1)^2\equiv 1$, $(\pm 2)^2\equiv 4$, $(\pm 3)\equiv 2$ mod $7$, so $-1$ isn't a quadratic residue mod $7$.

Another way here is noticing that $7$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, so by [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B11_and_the_first_supplement) (or a separate lemma, which is a lot easier to prove than quadratic reciprocity) $-1$ isn't a quadratic residue mod $7$.

Answer (score 0):

Since congruence arithmetic is unfamiliar we give a solution avoiding them.

Note $\ 7\mid 2m\,\Rightarrow\, 7\mid 7m-3(2m) = m.\,$ So $\,\  7\mid 2(1+q^2)\,\Rightarrow\, 7\mid 1+q^2$

Dividing $\,q\,$ by $\,7\,$ we have $\, q = a + 7b\,$ with remainder $\,a\,$ satisfying $\,0\le a \le 6$

Thus $\ 1+q^2 = 1+a^2+14ab+49b^2 = 1+a^2 + 7(2ab+7b^2)$

so $\ 7\mid 1+q^2\,\Rightarrow\, 7\mid 1+a^2\,$ for some $a$ with $\,0\le a\le 6,\,$ a contradiction (check all $7$ cases).